# Anchor Peers config within a channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

1. Should we only add anchor peers to a channel to enable cross-org communication?
2. If yes, from my understanding chaincode is only applied at a channel level, does that mean any peer thats not in the channel will not have the correct chaincode?
3. If I were to add all of the peers to a channel then is there a point for declearing any anchor peers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To be precise, it allows cross-org mutual discovery of peers, and therefore it is crucial for cross org endorsements if the client uses [service discovery](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery-overview.html).
2. This has nothing to do with chaincodes... chaincodes are installed independently to channels.
3. Yes. Because otherwise peers from different organizations won't be able to find each other.

Comment: so just to follow up on the first question. Do we have to include all peers to the channel in order for the non-anchor peers to interact with the blockchain? If i create a channel with ONLY anchor peers can other non-anchor peers from other org function properly?

Comment: Okay I will rephrase it.
1. Are you supposed to enroll non-anchor peers to a channel? Can I only enroll the anchor peer from each organization to a channel?
2.If I enroll only the anchor peers to a channel, are organizations able to discover other orgs non-anchor peers?

Comment: if you don't join a peer to a channel, it doesn't get the data of the channel... and doesn't participate in the channel and can't endorse any transaction on the channel.